# How should i name a function that retrieves smt but inserts it if it doesn't exists

Tags: php, naming-conventions

it might sound stupid but i am having a hard time naming a function.
My function returns the id of the tag with the given $name parameter; but it should create a new tag if it doesn't exist (and return the id of the new tag).

Here is my code:

```
public function get_tag_insert_if_not_exists($name)
{
    $tag = $this->get_tag_with_name($name);
    if ($tag === FALSE) {
        return $this->insert_tag($name);
    }
    return $tag->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `getOrCreate` is a more common name for this. Probably doesn't make much of a difference, but I've seen this used more commonly than `getOrInsert`.

Answer (score 1):

```
getInsertTag();
```

or more verbous/uglier

```
getOrInsertTag();
```